# VUEJS - how to dynamically bind a textarea to datatable field

Tags: vue.js

I want to  add editable fields to datatable row when the user click the add button. but it is returning undefined values and not yet editable  here
is the sample of the code

```
addPastor() {
  function bindTextArea() {
    return {
      template: `<textarea></textarea>`
    };
  }
  //this is the values to be displayed
  let empObj = {
    first_name: bindTextArea(),
    last_name: bindTextArea(),
    other_names: bindTextArea(),
    department: bindTextArea(),
    date_of_birth: bindTextArea(),
    phone: bindTextArea(),
    first_timer: bindTextArea(),
    second_timer: bindTextArea()
  };
  this.desserts = [];
  this.desserts.push(empObj);
  //console.log(this.desserts);
},
deletePastor() {}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like a vue way - my guess here is you are using somth like vuetify - best is to check their examples and vue docs for `v-if`, `slots`. e.g. vuetify v-datatable you'd go with:

```
<v-datatable
   :items="dessert"
>
    <template #item={item}>
      <edit-row v-if="item.isEditable" :item="item" />
      <static-row v-else :item="item" />
    </template>
</v-datatable>
```

[check docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#api)

[for slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html)

---

Implies that other frameworks are similar